# How to pass arguments into Javascript functions on websites via console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm trying to bypass a timer in a course I'm currently taking in which I cannot advance to the next page unless the timer has hit 0.  I am using TamperMonkey in order to set the value of a function to a value that will allow me to get the timer to hit 0 but to no avail.  How do I pass an argument into a function in Javascript through console or tampermonkey in order to set the timer equal to 0 and advance through every page?  I program mainly in Python and this is my first time trying to code in Javascript.

Using latest version of Google Chrome and Tampermonkey.  My current Tampermonkey script invalidates the timer and sets it equal to a null value (----)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    window.seconds = 0;
    var scriptContent = "UpdateTimer('TimeRemainingClock', 0, 'DOWN')";
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Doesn't get anything.

Code for the website's JS is:

```
var pageLoaded = 0; 
var timerStatus = 'pending';
var secondsRemaining = -1;
var secondsElapsed = -1;
var startTicks = 0;
var errorCount = 0;
var estimatedSecondsRemaining = -1;
var zeroTimeCounter = 0;
var intervalIdUpdateBothTimers;
var nonLinearGuid = null;

function UpdateElapsedTimer()
{
    var s = secondsElapsed + (GetTickDiff()/1000);  
    UpdateTimer('TotalTimeClock', s, 'UP');
}

function GetTickDiff()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var tickDiff = d.getTime() - startTicks;
    return tickDiff;
}

function UpdateRemainingTimer()
{

    var s = secondsRemaining - (GetTickDiff()/1000);

    estimatedSecondsRemaining = s;

    if (s < 0) s = 0;

    UpdateTimer('TimeRemainingClock', s, 'DOWN');
}

function UpdateTimer(ClockID,ElapsedSeconds,ClockDirection){


    //check to see if we can run this code yet
    if(document.getElementById && document.getElementById(ClockID) != null){

        //declare vars
        var _Seconds = 0;
        var _Minutes = 0;
        var _Hours = 0;

        //Format Seconds
        _Seconds = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds % 60);
        if(_Seconds <= 9) {
            _Seconds = "0"+_Seconds;
        }

        //Format minutes
        _Minutes = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/60 % 60);
        if(_Minutes <= 9) {
            _Minutes = "0"+_Minutes;
        }

        //Format hours
        _Hours = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/3600);
        if(_Hours <= 9){
            _Hours = "0"+_Hours;
        }

        document.getElementById(ClockID).innerHTML = _Hours + ":" + _Minutes + ":" + _Seconds;

        if (timerStatus != 'active')
        {   
            setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000);  
            return;
        }

        if(ElapsedSeconds > 0 || ClockDirection == "UP"){

            if(ClockDirection == "UP")
            {
                ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds - 1;
            }

            //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000);            
        }
        else{
            //Timer has hit zero. Lets make sure the next buttons are visible.
            $('#next_top').show();
            $('#next_bot').show();
        }   
    }
    else if(!pageLoaded) //call function again in 100ms
    {
        //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',100);
    }
```

When using TamperMonkey script, output is:
TimerUtils.01.js:262 Uncaught TypeError: UpdateTimer is not a function
    at UpdateElapsedTimer (VM27051 TimerUtils.01.js:262)
    at UpdateBothTimers (VM27051 TimerUtils.01.js:200)
    at :1:1

I understand the idea of scopes but do not understand what my output should be.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems to me that UpdateTimer is null or was redefined to another value before UpdateElapsedTime was called. Are you calling UpdateTimer before UpdateElapsedTimer? Maybe there is some code that redefines UpdateTimer if you call it out of order. I think that the answer is in TimerUtils.01.js, could you share it ?

Answer (score -1):

Bump

```
var pageLoaded = 0; 
var timerStatus = 'pending';
var secondsRemaining = -1;
var secondsElapsed = -1;
var startTicks = 0;
var errorCount = 0;
var estimatedSecondsRemaining = -1;
var zeroTimeCounter = 0;
var intervalIdUpdateBothTimers;
var nonLinearGuid = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('AutoSave()', 120000);
    intervalIdUpdateBothTimers = setInterval('UpdateBothTimers()', 1000);

    if (timerStatus == 'pending') {
    
        var totaltimeclock = document.getElementById('TotalTimeClock');
        if (totaltimeclock != null) {
            document.getElementById('TotalTimeClock').innerHTML = '-- \: -- \: --';
        }

        var timeremainingclock = document.getElementById('TimeRemainingClock');
        if (timeremainingclock != null) {
            document.getElementById('TimeRemainingClock').innerHTML = '-- \: -- \: --';
        }

        StartTimer();
    }

});

function loaded(i,f) {
    if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(i) != null) 
    {
        f(); 
    }
    else if (!pageLoaded) setTimeout('loaded(\''+i+'\','+f+')',100);
}

function SuspendTimer() {
    UpdateBothTimers();
    
    if (timerStatus == 'active') {
        var data = "s=2&cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();
        timerStatus = 'suspended';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Courses/ajax/CourseData.aspx",
            data: data,
            success: displayTime,
            async: false
        });

        clearInterval(intervalIdUpdateBothTimers);
    }
    
}

function AutoSave()
{
    if (timerStatus == 'active')
    {
        SaveTime();
    }
}

function SaveTime()
{
    var data = '';
    if (typeof window.IsScormPage === 'undefined')
    {
        data = "cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&sp=false";
    }
    else
    {
        data = "cp=" + this.location.pathname + "&sp=true";
    }

    data += "&nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Courses/ajax/CourseData.aspx",
        data: data,
        success: displayTime,
        async: false
    });  
}

function StartTimer()
{
    timerStatus = 'active';

    SetNonLinearGuid();
    SaveTime();
}

// Sets the nonLinearGuid with the one in the DOM
// the GUID was generated in the server side and
// passed it to the client side (DOM)
function SetNonLinearGuid()
{
    var $nonLinearGuid = $("#nonLinearGuid");

    if ($nonLinearGuid === undefined)
    {
        $nonLinearGuid = $("input[name=nonLinearGuid]");
    }

    if ($nonLinearGuid.length)
    {
        nonLinearGuid = $nonLinearGuid.val() || null;
        window.nonLinearGuid = window.nonLinearGuid || nonLinearGuid;
    }
}

function GetNonLinearGuid() {
    var nlg = (window.NonLinearGuid || nonLinearGuid),
        admin = getQueryStringByName("admin", parent.window.location.href) || "";

    if (admin.toLowerCase() == "d3v") {
        printNonLinearGuid(nlg);
    }

    return nlg;
}

function getQueryStringByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function displayTime(result)
{
    
    if (result.isOk == false)
    {
        alert(result.message);
    }
    else
    {   
        var d = new Date();
        startTicks = d.getTime();
        
        secondsRemaining = parseInt($(result).find("SecondsRemaining").text());
        secondsElapsed = parseInt($(result).find("SecondsElapsed").text());
        redirectUrl = $(result).find("RedirectUrl").text();

        var suspendTimer = $(result).find("SuspendTimer").text();
        var dataNonLinearGuid = "?nlg=" + GetNonLinearGuid();
        
        if (redirectUrl != "") {
            location.href = redirectUrl;
        }
        
        isError = $(result).find("Error").text();
        
        if (isError == "true")
        {
            errorCount++;
            
            if (errorCount > 3)
            {
                logout();
            }
        }

        isOverworked = $(result).find("IsOverworked").text();
        if (isOverworked == "true") 
        {
            location.href = "/Courses/MyAccountNonLinear.aspx" + dataNonLinearGuid;
        }

        if (suspendTimer.length > 0) {
            if ($.trim(suspendTimer).toLowerCase() == "true") {
                SuspendTimer();
            }
        }       
    }
}

function logout()
{
    window.top.location.href = "/Courses/loggedout.aspx";
}

function UpdateBothTimers() {
    
    if (timerStatus != 'active') return;
    
    if (secondsElapsed >= 0)
    {    
        UpdateElapsedTimer();
        //secondsElapsed++;
    }

    if (secondsRemaining >= 0) {
        UpdateRemainingTimer();
    }

    if (estimatedSecondsRemaining <= 0 && zeroTimeCounter == 0) {
        zeroTimeCounter++;     
        SaveTime();
    }
}
var lang;
function qt(m,lng) {
    
    $('#timeRemaining').css('display', 'none');
    setTimeout("$('#EOMQuiz').submit();", m * 1000);
    lang = lng;
    setTimeout('updateQ('+ m +')', 1000);
}

function updateQ(m) {
   
    --m;
    var text;
    if (lang == 'es') {
        text = 'Entregar - ' + m + ' segundos restantes para completar la prueba';
    }
    else {
        text = 'Submit - ' + m + ' seconds remaining to complete the quiz';
    }
   
    if (m > 0) {
       
        setTimeout('updateQ('+m+')', 990);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
       text ='Submitting... Please Wait.';    
    }
   
    if (m <= 10 && m > 0)
    {
        if (m % 2 == 0)
        {
            $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#eomsubmitDiv').css('background-color', '#FFFFAA');        
        }
           
    }
    
    $('#eomsubmit').attr('value', text);
}

function UpdateElapsedTimer()
{
    var s = secondsElapsed + (GetTickDiff()/1000);  
    UpdateTimer('TotalTimeClock', s, 'UP');
}

function GetTickDiff()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var tickDiff = d.getTime() - startTicks;
    return tickDiff;
}

function UpdateRemainingTimer()
{
    
    var s = secondsRemaining - (GetTickDiff()/1000);

    estimatedSecondsRemaining = s;
    
    if (s < 0) s = 0;
    
    UpdateTimer('TimeRemainingClock', s, 'DOWN');
}

function UpdateTimer(ClockID,ElapsedSeconds,ClockDirection){

    
    //check to see if we can run this code yet
    if(document.getElementById && document.getElementById(ClockID) != null){

        //declare vars
        var _Seconds = 0;
        var _Minutes = 0;
        var _Hours = 0;
        
        //Format Seconds
        _Seconds = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds % 60);
        if(_Seconds <= 9) {
            _Seconds = "0"+_Seconds;
        }
        
        //Format minutes
        _Minutes = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/60 % 60);
        if(_Minutes <= 9) {
            _Minutes = "0"+_Minutes;
        }
        
        //Format hours
        _Hours = Math.floor(ElapsedSeconds/3600);
        if(_Hours <= 9){
            _Hours = "0"+_Hours;
        }
        
        document.getElementById(ClockID).innerHTML = _Hours + ":" + _Minutes + ":" + _Seconds;
        
        if (timerStatus != 'active')
        {   
            setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000);  
            return;
        }

        if(ElapsedSeconds > 0 || ClockDirection == "UP"){
        
            if(ClockDirection == "UP")
            {
                ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ElapsedSeconds = ElapsedSeconds - 1;
            }
            
            //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',1000);            
        }
        else{
            //Timer has hit zero. Lets make sure the next buttons are visible.
            $('#next_top').show();
            $('#next_bot').show();
        }   
    }
    else if(!pageLoaded) //call function again in 100ms
    {
        //setTimeout('UpdateTimer(\''+ClockID+'\','+ElapsedSeconds+',\''+ClockDirection+'\')',100);
    }
}   


function DisplayNextButtons(){
    $('#next_top').show();
    $('#next_bot').show();
}

function hideNextButtons(){
    $('#next_top').hide();
    $('#next_bot').hide();
}
```

Comment: It would be good to explain inside your answer what the problem was and how you solved it. Just "bump" is not very helpful.